# Cracking WPA2 using Intel HD Graphics GPU

Tags: linux, passwords, brute-force, wpa2

I use Linux Kali and yesterday have captured a WPA handshake of my network. I want to crack it's password - but my CPU with aircrack-ng checks only about 2000 keys per second. In my laptop I have got Intel HD Graphics 4600 GPU - I want to use it to cooperate with CPU in cracking password (I read that could make this proccess faster 20 times!). Is there any way to do that? I know about `hashcat`, but, if I'm not wrong, it is only for NVIDIA or AMD/ATI GPUs.

Comment: There should be OpenCL support in the Intel IGP.

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong, you would need a proper GPU to accelerate hashcat. A popular choice as an alternative to hashcat is crunch http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/files/crunch-wordlist/ For which google will give you a bevy of tutorials on the subject. I'm surprised you getting as high as 2000kps given the state of it.

Generally speaking you want several GPU's working under oclHashCat to get this processed in any reasonable amount of time. (they post their statistics http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/)

Comment: Crunch does not handle cracking, it is just a generator, it is not any alternative to hashcat, You can pipe its output to hashcat or aircrack-ng if you want.

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers:

- As of hashcat version 3.00, CPU and GPU hashcat were merged into a single project, using OpenCL to abstract the platforms.
- If you install the Intel OpenCL runtime for GPUs, you can use hashcat on Intel GPU hardware.
- Kali's OpenCL is currently not considered to be reliable by the hashcat project. Using a different distro is currently (2018) recommended.

Comment: "Kali's OpenCL is currently not considered to be reliable " I do not see why. Could you elaborate or source this statement? Could you tel us which version is supposed to be "unreliable". "Kali OpenCL" is "de facto" the package from Debian SID repository. As you know it has a "roling release" approach and packages changes frequently. If any problem occurred in the past with a concrete past version it is now fix (in 2018)

Comment: @kcdtv Good catch and fair point. It turns out that I have been operating from what may be outdated information. The hashcat FAQ explains why this used to be true, but is no longer true: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#why_does_hashcat_not_work_with_my_kali_operating_system (That being said, I haven't tried it myself, though; I am interested in doing so, to verify for myself). Have you used it with success? If so, what versions/combinations?

Comment: From Kali Linux repositories in an up to date system you would get `hashcat v.4.1.0`. Opencl is in version `2.2.x`. Notice that there are several packages available in Kali repositories: Two package "legacy" for old nvidia cards, one for the newest one, an other package that I guess could be interesting for this intel card: `mesa-opencl-icd/kali-rolling 17.3.9-1 amd64`...  Saying so I do not know if it will work with this card model: I have a "not so new" nvidia cards which works correctly with hashcat in Kali. But it is an "easy one" that is supported since a long time.

Comment: Reading the link you posted (thanks) they point out to"Kali still used a very old glibc version." I don't know why it was like this. Now the system use a package "2.27-3" which is up to date as the version 2.27 is thew latest stable release of glibc.

Answer (score 0):

If you would try to crack it with the same hardware today then I would rather recommend an online hash crack website first. Search for `online hash crack WPA` in your browser the first 2-3 results would do it. These sites are fully legit and they try to crack your pcap with a limited wordlist freely, what is usually good enough for weaker passwords. Some users change the factory default passwords to a even weaker pass (eg. only digits).